# Tic tac toe implementation using Minimax tree in Parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I am trying to find a source code for implementing Tic tac toe game using Minimax tree in parallel either in Java using Fork/Join or in C/C++ using pthread. I could find a lot of serial version of the game but not a parallel version.

I saw this question:
[How many threads are okay to use for tic-tac-toe using minimax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169547/how-many-threads-are-okay-to-use-for-tic-tac-toe-using-minimax) by @good_evening

but I couldn't find any source code.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find one in a quick search.

Here's a [parallel minimax chess program](https://github.com/gsig/java-chess-ai).   It is probably more instructive, because it is a much more "practical" example.